# C# Put EventHandler in get statement

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am trying to put in an event handler in a user control, where an event handler of the controls in the control are linked to this event handler, as so:

```
    public EventHandler PicDoubleClick
    {
        get
        {
            return pictureBox1.DoubleClick;
        }
        set
        {
            pictureBox1.DoubleClick += value;
            label1.DoubleClick += value;
            label2.DoubleClick += value;
        }
    }
```

But I get the following compile error at line 5:

```
1>C:\Users\jorda\source\repos\Encyclo1\Encyclo1\Pic.cs(20,36,20,47): error CS0079: The event 'Control.DoubleClick' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
```

I want the property to return an event handler it goes out to. Sort of like a property with no value of its own but instead someone else's.

I have got the set statement working, though it works unusually. But is there any way to return the event handler? Is there a more proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events should have `add`/`remove` accessors:

```
public event EventHandler PicDoubleClick
{
    add
    {
        pictureBox1.DoubleClick += value;
        label1.DoubleClick += value;
        label2.DoubleClick += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        pictureBox1.DoubleClick -= value;
        label1.DoubleClick -= value;
        label2.DoubleClick -= value;
    }
}
```

However, it may be a better idea to intercept the event, because otherwise the sender won't be what the caller expects; i.e.

```
void SomeInitMethod() {
   pictureBox1.DoubleClick += (s,a) => OnSomeEvent();
   label1.DoubleClick += (s,a) => OnSomeEvent();
   label2.DoubleClick += (s,a) => OnSomeEvent();
}
public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
protected virtual void OnSomeEvent() {
    SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: I'll try that. That probably explains the unusual syntax of a EventHandler.

Comment: @JordanFerrazza just note the bit I added about intercepting being preferable

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate on the second part? I get you, but I don't know how to apply the code.

Such as how do I apply it if there is "Invoke(this"?

Comment: @JordanFerrazza it should *just work* as written, if you have a recent C# compiler; if you have an older compiler, you'll need: `EventHandler tmp = SomeEvent; if (tmp != null) tmp.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);`

Comment: Nah, it's just hard to understand. (I have used the first part.)